AuthenticationError 401 - Principal Does Not Have Access to API/Operation when using Azure Open AI with Python SDK
Issue Summary:
Encountering an AuthenticationError with error code 401 when attempting to access the OpenAI API. The error message indicates that the principal does not have access to the API/Operation.
Expected Outcome:
The service principal should have access to the specified API/Operation based on the roles and permissions assigned.
Actual Outcome:
Receiving the following error message: Principal does not have access to API/Operation. This prevents the service principal from accessing the API as expected.
Environment Details:

Subscription ID: Redacted

Role(s) Assigned: Contributor , User

Application ID: Redacted

API/Operation: Microsoft.CognitiveServices/accounts/listKeys/action

Azure Resource: Redacted


Appreciate any support on the above

You need to have Cognitive Services OpenAI User or Cognitive Services OpenAI Contributor or Cognitive Services User role to access the open ai resource for inferencing.
Next, use below code.
from azure.identity import get_bearer_token_provider, ClientSecretCredential
from openai import AzureOpenAI
cred = ClientSecretCredential(client_id="<yourClientId>",tenant_id="YourTenantId",client_secret="<ClientSeceret>")
token_provider = get_bearer_token_provider(
    cred, "https://cognitiveservices.azure.com/.default"
)

client = AzureOpenAI(
    api_version="2024-02-15-preview",
    azure_endpoint="https://v-jgsopenai.openai.azure.com/",
    azure_ad_token_provider=token_provider
)

response = client.chat.completions.create(
    model="gpt35", # model = "deployment_name".
    messages=[
        {"role": "system", "content": "You are a helpful assistant."},
        {"role": "user", "content": "Does Azure OpenAI support customer managed keys?"},
        {"role": "assistant", "content": "Yes, customer managed keys are supported by Azure OpenAI."},
        {"role": "user", "content": "Do other Azure AI services support this too?"}
    ]
)

print(response.choices[0].message.content)

Output:

